# PayPal Adaptive Payments: error 569059, Instant payments can't be pending

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Does anybody know what error 569059 means? I can't find it in PayPal's doc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `requireInstantFundingSource` set to `True`? A 569059 error occurs when a buyer is trying to complete a payment you've required to be instant with a funding source that requires time approve - like a bank transfer / echeck.

Comment: Hey Patrick, I just saw this, somehow I didn't get a notification... Thanks for the answer, I *just* got a reply from developer support and this makes sense.

Comment: We've been backlogged on tickets for awhile so it's been difficult to get responses to tickets out quickly. What is the ticket number you submitted? I want to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal just replied, this is what they said:

> This was a payment decline. The buyer/sender will need to contact
>   customer support if they wish to discuss it.
>
> You can contact our Customer Service agents by phone at:
>   US/CA: 1-888-221-1161
>   UK: 08707 307 191
>   Australia: 1-800-073-263
>   Germany: 0180 500 66 27
>   Other: 1-402-935-2080